# How can we use Twist() to rotate turtle two times making different circles in ROS python?

Tags: python, ros, ubuntu-20.04, rospy

I want to move the turtle in circle two times making two different circles, and I'm using Twist()
but when ever I give two different twist and values for the same publisher only one for them is published, even I have tried using two different publishers, but getting the same output. So anyone can please tell me how to publish the Twist() with two different values.

```
 pub = rospy.Publisher('turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
 pub_1 = rospy.Publisher('turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)

 # Create a Twist message and add linear x and angular z values
 move_cmd = Twist()
 move_cmd.linear.x =   1.0
 move_cmd.linear.y =   0.0
 move_cmd.angular.z = -1.0
 move_cmd_1 = Twist()
 move_cmd_1.linear.x =  1.0
 move_cmd_1.linear.y =  0.0
 move_cmd_1.angular.z = 1.0

 # Save current time and set publish rate at 10 Hz
 now = rospy.Time.now()
 rate = rospy.Rate(10)

 # For the next 6 seconds publish cmd_vel move commands to Turtlesim
 while rospy.Time.now() < now + rospy.Duration.from_sec(10.5):
     pub.publish(move_cmd_1)

     pub_1.publish(move_cmd_1)
     rate.sleep()
```

Comment: where is your code? Without code question is only waste of time.

Comment: What are you expecting here? Do you think your turtle is able to break itself? You should try to do some small break between your two publications (not that you need to keep ROS spinning here to ensure pubilcations are done).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code here. First, you're actually publishing the same message on both publishers. Secondly, it's not a good idea to publish two values on the same topic right after each other like that. If the subscriber is caching the most recent value there is a very good chance it will only ever see/use the second value published. If you're trying to alternate, try this code instead. Note that I decreased the spin rate and the publishers are alternating per loop.

```
 pub = rospy.Publisher('turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)

 # Create a Twist message and add linear x and angular z values
 move_cmd = Twist()
 move_cmd.linear.x =   1.0
 move_cmd.linear.y =   0.0
 move_cmd.angular.z = -1.0
 move_cmd_1 = Twist()
 move_cmd_1.linear.x =  1.0
 move_cmd_1.linear.y =  0.0
 move_cmd_1.angular.z = 1.0

 # Save current time and set publish rate at 10 Hz
 now = rospy.Time.now()
 rate = rospy.Rate(3)
 loop_count = 0

 # For the next 6 seconds publish cmd_vel move commands to Turtlesim
 while rospy.Time.now() < now + rospy.Duration.from_sec(10.5):
     if loop_count % 2 == 0:
         pub.publish(move_cmd)
     else:
         pub.publish(move_cmd_1)
     loop_count += 1
     rate.sleep()
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working, i want to move turtle in lemniscate shape